Why do I get "invalid command 'git'" after editing the "rebase todo" and trying to continue?
I tried to switch my branch but I could not because I was rebasing:
fatal: cannot switch branch while rebasing
Consider "git rebase --quit" or "git worktree add".

It showed:
Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
   pick d51f32027a0 Correct last code block not annotated
   pick 7380fa4a8e7 changed all @doc issues
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)

So I did
git rebase --edit-todo

It opened a file in Vim, which I edited as follows:
pick d51f32027a0 Correct last code block not annotated
pick 7380fa4a8e7 changed all @doc issues
     git rebase --continue
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor

After closing this, I expected it would continue with the rebase. But now there is this output:
git rebase --continue
error: invalid command 'git'
error: invalid line 3:      git rebase --continue
error: please fix this using 'git rebase --edit-todo'.

What should I do?

You're currently part-way through a rebase. Rebasing is stateful, at least while you're resolving conflicts. You need to advance to the next step (or give up) explicitly, following the instructions provided by rebase. So, either abort the rebase or finish it normally, or create a separate work tree, just like git told you to.

@Useless Would like to,but how? will edit

@phd Edited,pls take a look.

@phd does not work,take a look.

You inserted text "git rebase --continue" into the rebase todo file. git rebase --edit-todo again, remove the text, leave only pick lines, save, exit and run git rebase --continue in the command line.

ok,now it shows merge conflicts.

Those you need to resolve yourself, it's your code/text, we cannot help. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+resolve+merge+conflict

@phd yes,for sure!

There are no automatic ways to resolve merge conflicts, alas. If there were Git would apply them automatically itself.

Beside removing the invalid line in your rebase todo file, and resolving conflicts, note that:

resolving the rebase means (once the merge conflict markers have been removed):
git add <file-with-conflicts>
git rebase --continue


aborting can be done with git rebase --abort now, or git rebase --quit later on if you forgot to abort the rebase (that might be your case here, where you realize a rebase is in progress when you attempt to switch branch).

accessing main is always possible by adding a worktree:
git worktree add ../main-worktree main

That way, you have a separate folder where main is checked out, letting you continue your rebase in the original directory.



You inserted text git rebase --continue into the rebase todo file.
Run git rebase --edit-todo again, remove the text, leave only pick lines, save, exit and run git rebase --continue in the command line.

Based on a comment by phd.
